# How to calculate sum for many objects

Tags: python, django

There is code:

```
ids = []
menu = {}
for offer in customer_order.split(';'):
    id, count = offer.split(':')
    ids.append(id)
    menu[int(id)] = int(count)
mList = Goods.objects.filter(id__in=ids,
                             kind_cost=1).values('id', 'cost')
for item in mList:
    id = item['id']
    cost = item['cost']
    menu[id] = menu[id] * cost
return sum(menu.values())
```

`customer_order` is a string that includes: '32:5;45:2;555:23' and etc.

My question: I sure there is the best solution for achieve a result. Can anybody help me look for the solution? Please, share links for read how to improve the code

Tnx!

UPD: I need summarize cost of all goods

Comment: `customer_order` is a dict? `dict` doesn't have a `split` method.... What is it you're trying to do -- you describe it in words rather than code?

Comment: What `Goods.objects.` is supposed to do?

Comment: @Marcin `Goods` is a django model. `objects.filter` is a database query that returns all the objects in that model following the filter (in this case, `id in ids AND kind_cost==1`)

Comment: @AdamSmith Opps .. Of course, `customer_order` is not dict. I have wrong wrote

Comment: @Marcin `Goods.objects` is simple queryset

Comment: @AdamSmith I need summarize cost of all goods

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `customer_order` is a string that looks like a dict (possibly JSON?) If it's JSON you should use the `json` module to parse it, but I'll go ahead and work under the assumption that it's actually a native python dictionary object as a string.

```
import ast

customer_order = ast.literal_eval(customer_order)
# makes this into an ACTUAL dict...

mList = Goods.objects.filter(id__in=customer_order.keys(),
                              kind_cost=1).values('id', 'cost')
# mList is now a list of dicts, each dict has keys `id` and `cost`

mList = dict([k.values() for k in mList])
# mList is now a single dict with id:cost pairings

# As a lengthy aside, you might be better off just doing:
#
# # mList = Goods.objects.filter(id__in=customer_order.keys(),kind_cost=1)
# # mList = {item.id:item.cost for item in mList}
#
# I find that must easier to read. If your items have a huge number of 
# columns, of course, this will vastly increase your query time. YMMV.

result = [qty * mList[id] for id,qty in customer_order.items()]
```

If `customer_order` is actually just key-value pairings that look like `key1:value1;key2:value2` then you'll have to do some preprocessing.

```
customer_order = {keyvalue.split(":") for keyvalue in customer_order.split(";")}
```

Comment: `customer_order` is not JSON It more similar CommaSeparatedField, but use semicolon.